# Punctuation in a Figure Caption (Abbreviation List)

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, dashes, em-dashes

I have question regarding punctuation in a caption of a figure.

Lets say, for example, I have a figure that depicts a certain schematic.

In the caption of the figure I want to list all the notations/abbreviations of the components, e.g.

> R — resistor, C — capacitor, L — inductor.

Technically, it seems, I would need to use an em dash, albeit everywhere else in the text I use the em dash without the surrounding spaces. If I keep the same style for the captions (which is something that most style guides insist), the list starts to look a bit "unusual" (*R—resistor, C—capacitor, L—inductor*).

What is the correct way to punctuate such a notation/abbreviation list?

Comment: Colons or equal-sign should do the trick: (R: resistor, R=resistor). Dashes are used as much to separate as join. I think of them as personal-space for words or phrases, where a dash can connect--and add--to a thought or a dash can -- wait, I've got something burning on the stove!

Comment: R resistor; C capacitor; L inductor

Comment: Conventions can be a better guide than grammar.